# Rx Java: Observable emits items before subscriber requests them

Tags: rx-java, observable

In the example below I want my subscriber to initially request two items from the observable and then every 5 seconds request two more:

```
public class RxJavaExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Observable.range(1, 6)
      .flatMap(testData -> {
        System.out.println("next item");
        return Observable.just(testData);
      }, 1)
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

      public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("requesting\n\n");
        request(2);
        Observable.interval(5, SECONDS)
            .subscribe(
                x -> {
                  System.out.println("requesting\n\n");
                  request(2);
                }); 
      }

      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("done");
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Integer testData) {
        System.out.println("OnNext");
      }
    });
 }
}
```

In this case I would expect the output to be:

```
requesting


next item
next item
OnNext
OnNext
requesting


next item
next item
OnNext
OnNext
requesting


next item
next item
OnNext
OnNext
done
```

But this is the actual output I get:

```
  next item
  requesting


  next item
  next item
  OnNext
  OnNext
  requesting


  next item
  OnNext
  OnNext
  next item
  requesting


  next item
  OnNext
  OnNext
  done
```

It seems like the Observable still emits one item before my subscriber requests anything. Why does this happen and is there a way to ensure the Observable only emits items once my subscriber requests them?

My example is rather contrived as I could just use `map` instead of `flatMap` which will give me the behaviour I want but for my real-world use case I do need to use `flatMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happens because of `flatMap()` operator, which adds request to the producer (source `range()` Observable) depending on the concurrency level requested, in your case you ask for concurrency of 1, so `flatMap` will call `request(1)` on the range `Observable`, thus the producer will produce single item before the subscriber requests anything.

Note, that you have 2 buffers here, although the `flatMap()` had requested item before the subscriber,it will just cause the range() to produce item, but you will not get not requested item at your `onNext()`, meaning your onNext sequence is as expected, it is just the `range()` that generates items in different manner.

BTW, in the default case of `flatMap()` meaning without concurrency limit, it will request infinite items, and with this case all the items will be generated immediately, not just one as your case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This still seems like strange behaviour. Why doesn't `flatMap` just wait for my subscriber to do the requesting? The reason I set the concurrency limit to 1 is because in my real-world use case I do an async operation in the `flatMap` and this operation can only handle a certain number of items per second. It seems wasteful for the Observable to emit items when nothing has been requested.

Comment: you're right, in short, this is technically possible, but this behavior comes historically from RX.NET,  you can take a deeper look and better explanation from David Karnok at his blog: http://akarnokd.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/flatmap-part-1.html under Backpressure section.